# How to group a column in a csv file by a range and plot histogram using python?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset which has over 20 columns and one of them is "Trip_distance" and there are over 100,000 rows in it.

This is a sample of the column "Trip_distance":

> [0 0
>   0.59
>   0.74
>   0.61
>   1.07
>   1.43
>   0.9
>   1.33
>   0.84]

and goes on.
I want to plot a histogram of this by grouping them into a range (as plotting all the 100,000 values won't make sense).

I tried

```
plt.hist(df['Trip_distance'],bins = no_of_rows)

plt.show()
```

But the code runs out of memory.

Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: what if you bin your trip_distance column first, then plot the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib is not very efficient for plotting large data sets. The problem is that you are using `bins=no_of_rows` (I'm guessing `no_of_rows` is `100 000` then). So, in the worst case, you could be trying to plot `100 000` bars in the histogram.

I would suggest you to reduce the number of bins (for the human eye, I don't think you will notice much difference between `100 000` bins and, lets say, `1000`). If you really want to plot a histogram, then it would make even more sense to reduce that number to `100` or less IMO.

If you want to plot large data sets you should probably take a look at other tools that implement more efficient back-ends and use, perhaps, OpenGL-based back-ends. See for example: [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/), [VisPy](http://vispy.org/), [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/), [Chaco](http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/)...

Comment: Lessened the number of bins to 100 and the plot seems pretty okay. However, still working on grouping them into a certain range. Thanks for you help!